# Django rest framework API is not responding when I run server with ASGI

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I used channels in my Django project and when I changed WSGI to ASGI then some of my APIs stopped responding.

```
 1. if customer_object.status == None:
 2. new_user, created = User.objects.get_or_created(username="abc", role_id=Role(1))
 3. new_user.set_password('abc')
 4. temp_object = User.objects.filter(id = self.request.data['user_id']).first()
 5. new_user.restaurant_id = temp_object.restaurant_id
 6. new_user.save()
 7. url = settings.API_URL+"/api/v1/auth/sign_in/"
 8. response = requests.post(url, data={'username': f"customer1", 'password': '123456'})
```

In the above-mentioned code at line 8 project not responds.

I used the python async-await method like

```
response = await requests.post(url, data={'username': f"customer1", 'password': '123456'})
```

It returns coroutine object and I try to get data from it by using

```
response.text
```

but it says couroutine object has no attribute text.

Please answer if anyone came accros this kind of situation.